# Select columns of dynamic tables of R data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dynamic

I am learning dynamic names using a for loop in R. To apply, I would like to extract some columns (same names: Name, Pop) of dynamic tables (table_CA, table_DC).

Here is my try:

```
states <- c("CA", "DC")
for (state in states) {
  assign(paste0("final_", state), paste0("table_", state)[,c("Name","Pop")]
}
```

The simple script does not work.

Using:

```
paste0("table_", state)[,c("Name","Pop")]
```

could be wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Can you advise me on this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Etienne Kintzler, for the right answer. It works! I should have paid more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `get`:

```
for (state in states) {
  assign(paste0("final_", state), get(paste0("table_", state))[, c("Name", "Pop")])
}
```

When you use `paste0("table_", state))[, c("Name", "Pop")]` you try **to select columns from a character**(called for instance `"final_CA"`) **and not from the actual object.**  Also selecting columns from a string is not possible since a string does not have two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to do.. So here is the answer
I am moving all the "Name" and "Pop" columns to a new table "newtable" from different tables with state "table_$state" name where state name changes from state to state.

```
# newtable to get the data out (has the same rows as one of the state tables)
newtable=data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow(table_CA),0))
states <- c("CA", "DC")
# Create a new column in newtable 
for (state in states){
eval(parse(text=paste0('newtable[,ncol(newtable)+1] <- table_', state,'[,c("Name","Pop")]')))}
```